# Visual Studio C# Text Editor Inactive Code Opacity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio, some code, like code enclosed in `#if false`/`#endif`, or unused `using`s, are dimmed.
I would like to change the opacity of such code, but I only could find a setting for the C++ editor (`Tools>Options>Text Editor>C/C++>View`).

Is there such a setting for the C# editor as well?
I did not find anything under `Tools>Environment>Fonts and Colors` either.

I am using VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools>Environment>Fonts and Colors` and select `Excluded Text`.